# MDX script to ignore zero's when calculating average

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to use MDX to create a calculated member for computing averages. I have two measures, [High School GPA] and [Has High School GPA]. [Has High School GPA] is set to 1 if [High School GPA] is numeric, else it's 0. So, in the past, the following calculated member worked just fine.

```
case
    when [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA] is null 
        or [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA] = 0
then null
    else
        [MEASURES].[High School GPA] / [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA]
end
```

Now, I need to exclude [High School GPA] = 0.00 from my average calculation even though [Has High School GPA] will be equal to 1. So, I modified my script as follows.

```
case
    when [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA] IS null 
        or [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA] = 0 
        or [MEASURES].[High School GPA] = 0
then null
    else
        [MEASURES].[High School GPA] / [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA]
end
```

However, my average is still including the records with [High School GPA] = 0.00. Any suggestion on how I can fix this?

Comment: In the SQL database are these GPA values 0 or null?

Comment: They can be both zero and null and I want to ignore both. We will be asking business to fix this on the source system so that we don't see any 0's in the future. But I need a temporary MDX solution :-)

Comment: If the GPA values are null in the SQL database, then [Has High School GPA] will be set to 0. However, if the GPA values are 0, [Has High School GPA] is set to 1 which is affecting the Averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to create a computed column on that table in the DSV. The calc should be:

NULLIF(GPA,0)

Then on the measures that use that column make sure the NullHandling property is set to Preserve. That should ensure both 0 and Null end up Null.

By the way, in MDX the IS NULL syntax isn't what you want. Use IsEmpty() instead. But in this case it's redundant because Null = 0 in MDX. So the proper MDX should be:

```
case
    when [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA] = 0 
        or [MEASURES].[High School GPA] = 0
then null
    else
        [MEASURES].[High School GPA] / [MEASURES].[Has High School GPA]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried implementing your solution, but I am afraid the average is still including the 0's. I added a CorrectHighSchoolGPA named calculation on the relevant table in the DSV using NULLIF(HighSchoolGPA,0) as the expression. I then created a new "Correct High School GPA ~~" measure to reference the named calculation ensuring that "NullProcessing" is set to Preserve. Finally, I created a new calculation as follows using the MDX you provided. However, I can assure you that the output still includes the 0's. I verified this by querying against the underlying tables. noluck

Comment: @Raj hmm. That all sounds right. What did you do exactly on the denominator Has High School GPA? Did you also set NullHandling=Preserve? What is the AggregateFunction on it?

Comment: I left NullProcessing to Automatic and the AggregateFunction is Sum.I even tried the following without the Has High School GPA, but got the same result.
case
        when IsEmpty([MEASURES].[Correct High School GPA ~~]) then null
    else
        [MEASURES].[Correct High School GPA ~~]/[MEASURES].[Has High School GPA ~~]
    end

Comment: What does the SQL column used for Has High School GPA return? A 0 if they have a 0 GPA? Assuming it returns a 0 when GPA is null or when GPA is 0 then I would have expected that to work since you use a Sum AggregateFunction.

Comment: Has High School GPA is set to 0 only if GPA is null, else it's set to 1.

Comment: @Raj please change that Has High School GPA to return null if GPA is 0